# How do i print out the decimal part of a number to a certain number of digits in C Sharp C#

Tags: c#

Can someone help me out ?
How do I print out the decimals of a number to a certain number of decimals in C# or should i say, how do you add trailing zeros to meet the specified number.

*Example:* printing to 7 decimals
5.66 should return 0.6600000
0.123456 should return 0.1234560

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to specify the number of digits is to use a [custom formatting string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings). '0' is a placeholder for a digit to always print, '#' would be an digit to print if relevant. So 7 decimals would be "0.0000000", There are also [standard formatting strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) that may be useful.

If you are not interested in the whole number part you can just subtract it:

```
var decimalPart = myValue - (int)myValue;
var str = decimalPart.ToString("0.0000000");
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution. You use the float function.

```
int double= Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine($"{num:fn}");
```

f specifies a float
n specifies the number of decimal places.
so f4 = to 4 decimal places